# Misunderstanding chain/2?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

If I have (with clpfd loaded):

```
test1(Ps):-
    permutation(Ps,[(a,1,1),(b,2,2),(c,3,1),(d,4,2)]), 
    Ps =[(L1,W1,X1),(L2,W2,X2),(L3,W3,Y1),(L4,W4,Y2)], 
    chain([W1,W2,W3,W4],#<).
```

And query:

```
?-test1(P).
P = [(a,1,1), (b,2,2), (c,3,1), (d,4,2)]
false
```

Which gives one answer as I expect, but with:

```
test2(Ps):-
    permutation(Ps,[(a,1,1),(b,2,2),(c,3,1),(d,4,2)]), 
    Ps =[(L1,W1,X1),(L2,W2,X2),(L3,W3,Y1),(L4,W4,Y2)], 
    chain([X1,X2],#<).
```

Query:

```
?-test2(P):-
P = [(a,1,1), (b,2,2), (c,3,1), (d,4,2)]
P = [(a,1,1), (b,2,2), (d,4,2), (c,3,1)]
P = [(a,1,1), (d,4,2), (b,2,2), (c,3,1)]
P = [(a,1,1), (d,4,2), (c,3,1), (b,2,2)]
P = [(c,3,1), (b,2,2), (a,1,1), (d,4,2)]
P = [(c,3,1), (d,4,2), (a,1,1), (b,2,2)]
P = [(c,3,1), (b,2,2), (d,4,2), (a,1,1)]
P = [(c,3,1), (d,4,2), (b,2,2), (a,1,1)]
false
```

I do not expect answers like:

```
P = [(c,3,1), (b,2,2), (d,4,2), (a,1,1)]
P = [(c,3,1), (d,4,2), (b,2,2), (a,1,1)]
```

Where the terms with as are after the terms with bs.
What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can now see what I was doing wrong.

As the answers:

```
P = [(c,3,1), (b,2,2), (d,4,2), (a,1,1)]
P = [(c,3,1), (d,4,2), (b,2,2), (a,1,1)]
```

Clearly have 1 and 2 in the third argument of the first two elements and so are meeting the chain constraint.